# Are categories containing a countably infinite amount of sets small or large?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, infinity

In category theory, small categories are those which all its objects and morphisms are sets and not proper classes. A category is small if it has a small set of objects and a small set of morphisms. We could say that a small set contains a finite amount of elements of that set.

But what about categories containing an infinite amount of sets (or more precisely, a countably infinite amount of sets)? Would that category necessarily be large? Or could it be small?

Comment: "We could say that a small set contains a finite amount \dots." Why do you think we could (truthfully) say that? What does finiteness have to do with smallness? Anyway, a category with countably many objects satisfies the part of the definition of "small" about objects. If it also has only a set of morphisms, then it's small; otherwise it's large. (Some people include in the definition of "category" the requirement that any two objects have only a set of morphisms between them; for such people the "otherwise" clause here can't arise.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "category containing a countably infinite amount of sets", as categories do not "contain" anything. However, I will try to clarify what "small category" means.

A small category has a set of objects and a set of morphisms. Sets (in general) may be countably infinite. (They may also be uncountably infinite.) The object-set of a category may be an arbitrary set; in particular, we may take our object-set to be a countably infinite sets, which is perhaps what you mean. The nature of the objects themselves is irrelevant: we could take the *elements* of our object-set to stand for proper classes, for instance. They just need to form a set.

If our category doesn't have object-sets and hom-sets, but instead has object-classes and hom-classes, then the category is large.

Comment: Nitpick that doesn't affect your point: a proper class cannot typically be an element of a set, essentially by definition.

Comment: @MarkS. You're right; I was being a little informal: I really meant we could represent proper classes using elements, though strictly speaking the proper classes themselves could not be contained in the sets. I've changed the wording to make this clearer. Thanks for pointing this out.